# error installing Joomla 3.2.3 on xampp server windows 8

Tags: redirect, joomla3.2

I have tried to install  joomla 3.2.3 on my xampp localhost, all  PHP Recommended settings are okay

http://postimg.org/image/byshuq5g9/

When installation process complete its Redirect again in install process steep three.

What should i do?

Regards

Rasel Ahmed

Comment: if i delete the installation folder it's say there is no configuration file found.

Answer (score 0):

if installation is completed, then I think you should delete the installation folder from C:\xampp\htdocs folder